# How to run multiple chat plugins in Rust video game

Tags: c#, plugins, chat

Hello I hope someone can help me. I run a modded games server and the plugins come in the form of a .cs, when installed they create a .json file. I have a plugin that gives a separate chat, now there is only one plugin on the market that does that but I have played on other server that have multiple chats so there has to be a way to alter the chat.cs file so the program will accept it I have tried renaming it and that didn't work is there any one that can help me ?

Comment: Did you mean the Rust video game?  The rust tag here is referring to the programming language.

Comment: I've edited your question to increase your chances of getting an answer.  If I got it wrong, feel free to change it back.